# PHP Notice: Undefined property: InboundEmail::$team_id

Tags: sugarcrm

I get an error/notice:

> "PHP Notice:  Undefined property: InboundEmail::$team_id"
>   Schedulers/_AddJobsHere.php on line 104,

I'm using Suagcrcrm CE 6.5.x

How to get rid of it?

Comment: `$team_id` is a reference to the default Team for any given record in the paid editions of Sugar. You shouldn't see it in the Community Edition. What sort of customization has been done to modules/Schedulers/_AddJobsHere.php? Or, did you perhaps downgrade from a paid edition?

Comment: thanks "@Matthew Poer" for your quick clarification.